# Is the classical Doopler Effect, for light shift, $1-v/c$, exact? What is it an approximation of?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, doppler-effect

Is the classical doopler effect for light shift equal to $1-v/c$ exact or an approximation of a classical formula? I know that it is an approximation of the relativistic formula, but what was the corresponding classical formula? I ask this because in Einstein's On the Electrodynamics of moving bodies he derives $\sqrt\frac{1-v/c}{1+v/c}$ and notes that it is different from the classical case. I'm not exactly sure what formula he is comparing it to.

Comment: Classical mechanics *is* the approximation of relativistic mechanics when the speed involved is small compared to that of light.

Comment: Doppler, not doopler...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is comparing $\sqrt{1-v\over 1+v}$ to the classical Doppler shift $(1-v)$ (where v is the velocity divided by c, since I use units where c=1). The formula you give $1-v\over 1+v$ doesn't have a classical interpretation, and Einstein reduces to Doppler's at slow speeds.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there was another, more exact, classical formula.

Comment: @BarryBarrett: What would it be? You can do a weird transformation of space and time in 1+1d space with right-moving light which keeps distances unstretched and keeps the speed of right-moving light constant, but this is just a mathematical trick, it has no physical significance.